# When reviewing tag wiki suggested edits, allow reviewers to supply a link to copied source, which the system can compare against, and act on

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, plagiarism

Sorry that the title's a mouthful; hopefully it will be clearer here.

When reviewing tag wiki suggestions, I notice that copied content gets [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7391450) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7361914) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7245580) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7221948) [again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7211302) [.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7211283)

It sure feels like very few people seem to know that "Copied Content" is an actual Reject reason, and approve all sorts of copied text.

To counteract this, it would be nice for reviewers to be able to supply a link to the copied source when rejecting the edit, that the system could then compare against.

If the system finds that, yes, the text in the tag wiki (or except) *is* contained verbatim in the link provided, and the tag wiki suggestion doesn't have a link to the source, then it automatically gets rejected.

We apparently don't want heavily-copied text in our tag wikis (hence the reject reason), it would be nice to be able to enforce that with some degree of success.

Comment: Good idea to let the system reject if it can verify that. Though that might be too cumbersome and error-prone, thus let that act as a moderator-flag which will keep the edit pending if it would otherwise be accepted.

Comment: "It sure feels like very few people seem to know that "Copied Content" is an actual Reject reason, and approve all sorts of copied text.", related: [Add tag wiki/excerpt audits with copied content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238339)

Comment: This probably isn't something that would happen enough to be a big problem, but what if a reviewer who wanted to reject an edit just copied the text out of the edit to some site somewhere, and then supplied a link to that site as the reject reason?

Comment: I hit a patch of these today. Copy the text, paste into search box, comes up exact hit, reject. *All* that I that I rejected that way were approved. Slightly off-actual-topic, but this was approved as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartbear I don't know how to flag that :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger: This one we probably want to burninate...

Comment: @Pekka 웃 - I could hug you:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7402252